# Trouble getting DelayedJob custom job to work: uninitialized constant UsersController::UserScrapeJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I've been trying to implement a DelayedJob custom job for a very long time, but am not finding much information online in terms of how to do this from start to finish, and am finding almost nothing that is not about sending mass emails (I've read collectiveidea's Github intro, Railscasts, SO questions, etc). As someone relatively new to Rails, I imagine that while the instructions are likely clear for someone more experienced, they are not clear enough for someone at my level to understand how to get this to work properly.

The aim of my task is to run the job, and then destroy the object (I am aware that DelayedJob destroys all completed jobs, but I also want the object destroyed from my database as well upon completion of the job.)

Previously, I was doing this with a DelayedJob non-custom job in my controller's `create` method: `user.delay.scrape`, followed by `user.delay.destroy`, which worked well. Therefore, everything else in my application is working fine, and the problem lies strictly in how I am setting up this custom job. However, for various reasons, it would be much better in this case to create a custom job.

Below is the current (non-working) way I have DelayedJob set up in my app. However, when I run the app, the console reports: `uninitialized constant UsersController::UserScrapeJob`. Any suggestions of how to get this to work properly would be greatly appreciated, and I'd be happy to answer any questions about this request.

Here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def scrape
  some code here...
 end
end
```

In my controller, the delayed job needs to function as part of the `create` method.

And here is my controller (with only the create method shown):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 if @user.save
  Delayed::Job.enqueue UserScrapeJob.new(user.id)
 else
  render :action => 'new'
 end
end
```

And here is the job file `userScrapeJob.rb`, which is in the `app/jobs` folder:

```
class UserScrapeJob < Struct.new(:user_id)  
 def perform
  user = User.find(user_id)
  user.scrape
  user.destroy
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo when you create the job, the name of the class is `UserScrapeJob`, with a capital 'U' (name of classes in ruby are constants).

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue UserScrapeJob.new(user.id)
```

You also have a syntax error in the if, it's `if ... else ... end`, and not `if ... end else ... end`

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work. It now reports back: `uninitialized constant UsersController::UserScrapeJob`. I did go ahead and remove the unnecessary `end` in the code.

Comment: That's because you have placed the file under app/jobs, which isn't loaded by default. Try moving the file to app/models or add the add/jobs directory to the autoload paths.

Comment: Brilliant. I can't tell you how long I've tried and failed to get this to work, and now thanks to you it does. Infinite thanks :)

Comment: Correction: It worked with one exception that I just fixed right now. The request went through, but the `user` object was no longer being destroyed from the regular (non-DelayedJob) database at the end of the job. The `user.destroy` method I had in the DelayedJob method only destroyed the DelayedJob object, which by default destroys on its own anyway for completed jobs. So to make sure the first object gets destroyed, right under the `perform` method's `user.scrape` method, I added `User.find(user_id).destroy`. This also destroyed the regular object as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming your job file from `userScrapeJob.rb` to `user_scrape_job.rb`.

When you call `UserScrapeJob.new` Rails converts the class name to [snake case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (i.e. user_scrape_job) and looks for the corresponding file of that name, user_scrape_job.rb.

Comment: Of course, that makes so much sense. I went ahead and made the change. That in combination with @aromero's answer made this work for the first time ever. Thanks a ton for your suggestion.